# Erro ao Executar Phpdoc no ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, documentação

Após baixar o phpDoc pelo composer.phar O que ocorreu de forma bem sucessida. 
Tento executar:

```
~$ ./phpdoc
```

No Terminal e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ubuntualex@ubuntualex-VirtualBox:~/vendor/bin$ ./phpdoc
Collecting files .. OK
Initializing parser .. OK
Parsing files



  [Exception]                                                                      
  No parsable files were found, did you specify any using the -f or -d parameter?  



project:run [-t|--target[="..."]] [-f|--filename[="..."]] [-d|--directory[="..."]] [--encoding[="..."]] [-e|--extensions[="..."]] [-i|--ignore[="..."]] [--ignore-tags[="..."]] [--hidden] [--ignore-symlinks] [-m|--markers[="..."]] [--title[="..."]] [--force] [--validate] [--visibility[="..."]] [--defaultpackagename[="..."]] [--sourcecode] [-p|--progressbar] [--template[="..."]] [--parseprivate] [--log[="..."]]
```

Estou usando composer 7.22
e Php 5.3
e Ubuntu 12.04

Qual parte deveo configurar ou estou executando o comando errado ?

Comment: O erro diz que você precisa especificar o diretório ou o arquivo para que ele gere a documentação:

exemplo: ./phpdoc -d /caminho/do/projeto/

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser descontextualizada porque já se resolve com a mensagem de erro dada pela aplicação, assim, não tem potencial de aproveitamento por futuros visitantes como Q&A.

Comment: Não entendi sua resposta ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva dei um voto de fechamento na questão, visto que você já resolveu e não é exatamente um problema de programação. A mensagem acima é automática, e aparece com o voto. Mas não se preocupe, é mera questão organizacional. De qq forma, você pode marcar sua resposta como aceita, clicando no "v" ao lado dela, ou simplesmente excluir a pergunta toda, se não for mais de utilidade.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solucionado

Especifiquei o diretório ou o arquivo para gerar a documentação: ./phpdoc -d /caminho/do/projeto/